# How to build a voice calling system with Electron + Vue

Tags: vuejs2, electron, voice

I want to ask how to build a voice calling system with Electron + Vue.The system interface allows you to enter Numbers to make a phone call. How do I make a successful voice call

Answer (score 1):

This is my job for 2 years and a half ago: build a cloud based phone system, with Electron and React on the front-end side. We are 40 engineers working everyday on it, so I can't obviously resume it in a StackOverflow answer of few characters.

Comment: I would like to know how to dial and talk on the front end of the communication Settings, can you give me a little direction?